# React "npm start" not working, MODULE_NOT_FOUND error

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm new to react.js and whenever I try to run the command "npm start", I get this error and I dont know why:

theapp@0.1.0 start C:\Users\jahmar lawrence\Desktop\webmyapp\theapp

> node index.js

internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:883
throw err;
^

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\jahmar lawrence\Desktop\webmyapp\theapp\index.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:880:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:725:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:72:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! theapp@0.1.0 start: `node index.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the theapp@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\jahmar lawrence\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-11-22T07_28_07_211Z-debug.log
```

If anyone could help me find a solution to this problem I'd really appreciate it, because I'm so confused on why this is happening, I looked all over for solution and can't find anything.

Comment: You must create a index.js file in your root/src folder.

Comment: Find template of index.js here - https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/tree/master/packages/cra-template/template/src

Comment: Thanks for the help but the solution for me was uninstalling node and downloading the latest version, everything is working fine now